# Kafka generating metadata request while executing kafka-console-consumer.sh

Tags: apache-kafka

H there,

I am running Apache Kafka on console for testing purpose. While executing `kafka-consumer.sh`, I am getting a message continuously without stopping like below:

```
{metadata.broker.list=xxxxxxxv.xxxxxxx.com:7xx3,dpxxxxxxx.bxxxx.com:7xxx, request.timeout.ms=30000, client.id=console-consumer-xx36x, security.protocol=PLAINTEXT}

{metadata.broker.list=xxxxxxxv.xxxxxxx.com:7xx3,dpxxxxxxx.bxxxx.com:7xxx, request.timeout.ms=30000, client.id=console-consumer-xx36x, security.protocol=PLAINTEXT}

{metadata.broker.list=xxxxxxxv.xxxxxxx.com:7xx3,dpxxxxxxx.bxxxx.com:7xxx, request.timeout.ms=30000, client.id=console-consumer-xx36x, security.protocol=PLAINTEXT}
```

This message keeps on going until i stop this forcefully. Please share your knowledge on this to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these messages generated with a log level?

Comment: Hi Aleksandar,  Thanks for you reply. I checked the server log and this is the info from the log file:   INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. Manager on Broker 1]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)

Comment: Which version of Kafka are you running? Did you check connectivity b/w the broker, zk and your consumer machine?